# Implementing "Gradient Descent Algorithm" in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I'm solving a programming assignment in `Machine Learning` course. In which I've to implement `Gradient Descent Algorithm` like below

[image]

I'm using the following code in Matlab

```
data = load('ex1data1.txt');
% text file conatins 2 values in each row separated by commas
X = [ones(m, 1), data(:,1)];
theta = zeros(2, 1);
iterations = 1500;
alpha = 0.01;

function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)
m = length(y); % number of training examples
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);
for iter = 1:num_iters
   k=1:m;
   j1=(1/m)*sum((theta(1)+theta(2).*X(k,2))-y(k))
   j2=((1/m)*sum((theta(1)+theta(2).*X(k,2))-y(k)))*(X(k,2))
   theta(1)=theta(1)-alpha*(j1);
   theta(2)=theta(2)-alpha*(j2);
   J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);
end
end

theta = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, iterations);
```

On running the above code I'm getting this error message

[image]

Its clear from the error message that, the result of the below expression

```
((1/m)*sum((theta(1)+theta(2).*X(k,2))-y(k)))*(X(k,2))
```

Is a vector, which we are trying to save in a scalar variable j2. I think X(k,2) is creating a problem, I've used it as an index to vector X to fetch a value from kth row and 2nd column. But On the other hand the whole vector is getting multiplied, Please suggest me how can I fix it.

Comment: Actually, Matlab have their own methods for these kind of problems. I know there is out of the question, but it was worth to say :)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should learn to read the error messages, and follow the leads from there:

- As stated in the error message, the number of elements on the left-hand-side and right-hand-side of the line `theta(2)=theta(2)-alpha*(j2);` are not the same, so try to spot which one it is. A standard trick is to do a `disp(size(...))` for all the various terms of the expression on the line before to check if all the things have the size you expect them to be.
- Some further reasoning: `theta(2)` and `alpha` appear to be scalars, so it is probably `j2` that is a non-scalar.
- Looking at the definition of `j2`, it seems that the `sum(...)` is a scalar, while the final `(X(k,2))` is a vector of size (m,1), so `j2` is also of size (m,1), while it should probably be a scalar. The error is probably that you need to include the `X(k,2)` part into the sum, so that the end result is a scalar.

Some other observations:

- You make the first column of `X` all ones, while you later only use the second column. Easier to just use `x = data(:,1)` and use that.
- you do `m=length(y); k=1:m;` and then use `y(k)` several times. Easier to just use `y` itself ...

You probably need to do something like

```
theta(1)=theta(1) - alpha / m * sum(whatever - y);
theta(2)=theta(2) - alpha / m * sum((whatever - y) .* x);
```

You need to figure out the rest yourself ...

Comment: I know the meaning of error message. Its coming because the result j2 storing is not a scalar value. The result of the operation that j2 is holding should be a scalar, But I won't be able to find a way to fix it. As I'm new to matlab, I've some problem regarding syntax.

Comment: Then what is your question? If you understand the error message, you should say so and maker clear what your problem is, don't leave us guessing ...

Comment: My question is what's the problem with the below expression and how can I fix it ((1/m)*sum((theta(1)+theta(2).*X(k,2))-y(k)))*(X(k,2)). Or is there any other way to implement the algorithm.

Comment: Please include that in the question, it is not clear as it is.

Comment: Hmm sorry I should have mentioned in the question

Comment: The problem may be with your understanding of the math. The product is _inside_ the summation in the image you showed. You've coded it outside, where it doesn't make sense.  MATLAB's error verifies that it doesn't make sense!